# Stop/start mediaplayer from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, stream, android-mediaplayer

i'm trying to play **stream radio** using `Mediaplayer` with **MP1** as variable of **Mediaplayer** i want to play it in all `Fragments` app,expect one `activity` (**ActivityOne**)  which is contains another `Mediaplayer` **MP2** to play,so i want to stop **MP1** when i'm in (**ActivityOne**) `activity`, and play **MP2** , and when i return from (**ActivityOne**) i want to resume **MP1**, my big problem is the (**ActivityOne**) called when i click `button` which is exist in `fragment`
my code below works only in one direction : 
when i return from (**ActivityOne**) activity, the music stops.

structure of the app : **MainAcitivty** > **Fragment** > **ActivityOne**

**MainActivity.java**

```
MediaPlayer MP1;
boolean prepared = false;
boolean started = false;
PlayerTask playerTask;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    playerTask = new PlayerTask();
    playerTask.execute(stream);
    /**/
       MusicButton = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    MusicButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    MusicButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (started && MusicButton.isChecked()) {
                started = false;
                MP1.pause();
                MusicButton.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                started = true;
                MP1.start();
                MusicButton.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    ProgressBar loadingRL = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AudioAttributes attribs = new AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA).setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).build();
            MP1.setAudioAttributes(attribs);

        } else {
            MP1.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        }
        loadingRL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            MP1.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            MP1.prepare();
            prepared = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MP1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer MP1) {
                MP1.start();

            }
        });
        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        MusicButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        MusicButton.setChecked(true);
         loadingRL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**ActivityOne.java**

```
    MediaPlayer MP2;
    boolean prepared = false;
    boolean started = false;
    ToggleButton music;
    PlayerTask playerTask = null;
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_for_ringtone);
        coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coord);
        MP2 = new MediaPlayer();
        playerTask = new PlayerTask();
        playerTask.execute(url);
}
  @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        ProgressBar pb = findViewById(R.id.progress);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                AudioAttributes attribs = new AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA).setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).build();
                MP2.setAudioAttributes(attribs);

            } else {
                MP2.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            if (!isCancelled()) {
                try {
                    MP2.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                    MP2.prepare();
                    prepared = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                MP2.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer MP2) {
                        MP2.start();
                    }
                });

            }
            return prepared;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            music.setEnabled(true);
            music.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            music.setChecked(true);
            all.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(Boolean aBoolean) {
            if (isCancelled() && MP2.isPlaying()) {
                MP2.stop();
            }
        }
    }

 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (playerTask != null && playerTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            if (MP2.isPlaying()) {
                MP2.stop();
            }
        } else if (playerTask != null && playerTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            playerTask.cancel(true);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

i spent 2 days to resolve this problem without any result ,please someone help me i will be thankful to him

Comment: Did you try to `override` methods `onPause` and `onResume` inside your fragment. So pause mp1 in `onPause` and resume it in `onResume` also if you are starting immediately mp2 you can do it in `onResume` or in `onCreate` and stop it inside `onPause`. Maybe some additional code will be needed like checkin si mp1 playing or paused as mp2 etc. but you get the point.

Comment: @Yupi thanks so much for your comment but how i cant **pause/resume ** **MP1** when i 'm in `fragment` and MP1 in `MainAcitivty` i can't control **MP1** when i'm in fragment

Comment: I think there is a solution which might work using one external library. I will post an answer but it will require some coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this by using `Otto` library. First create a new `Java` class but choose `enum` instead and inside `enum` you can add: PLAY and PAUSE for example:

```
public enum PlaybackEvent {
   PLAY, PAUSE
}
```

Then if you are not using custom `Application` class create one and extend `Application` and `override` inside `onCreate` method. Inside your `app gradle` add `compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'` then create an instance of `Bus` inside `Application` class and register. For example this would look like this:

```
public class MApplication extends Application {
public static Bus sBus = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.MAIN);
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sBus.register(this);
}
```

Don't forget to replace in manifest default application class with your new one

`<application
        android:name="com.packagename.MApplication"`

After that in your `MainActivity` class `override` and register/unregister your event bus in `onResume` and in `onPause`.

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
      MApplication.sBus.register(this);
    }
   catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
   try {
      MApplication.sBus.unregister(this);
    }
   catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

After that in `MainActivity` create a `public void` method passing as parameter `PlayBackEvent` and `Subscribe` so you can listen a message which will be send from your `fragment` class. For example:

```
 @Subscribe
public void handlePlaybackEvent(PlaybackEvent event) {
    switch (event) {
        case PLAY:
           if(MP1.isPlaying())
             MP1.pause();
            break;
        case PAUSE:
            if(!MP1.isPlaying())
             MP1.play();
            break;
    }
}
```

And last thing you have to do is to send the message from your `fragment` when starting second activity and that will go:

```
 MApplication.sBus.post(PlaybackEvent.PAUSE);
```

and of course you can also send a message to play again MP1 from second activity `overriding onBackPressed` putting inside line of code:

```
 MApplication.sBus.post(PlaybackEvent.PLAY);
```

Hope this will help you to resolve the problem.

Comment: thanks so much man for giving me some of your time,i have followed all the steps you've written but when i click backbutton to back from **ActivityOne**  to `fragment` music still stopped and if i want to play it i should click (play and pause toggle button) again

Comment: Didi you `override onBackPressed` method inside your second activity and inside `onBackPressed` use `MApplication.sBus.post(PlaybackEvent.PLAY);`

Comment: Okay if it's not playing after you return back probably the issue is in because `Otto` was unregister inside `onPause` so solution for that is to use `onDestroy` instead `onPause` and surround `MApplication.sBus.register(this);` in `onResume` with `try` and `catch` block so you don't exception when resume app.

Comment: thaaaanks so much i change some code and it's work ,thanks again please i have another question It may seem strange i put all radio stream code inside AsynTask as you see above in my post , my problem when i go quickly to ActivityOne before MP1 start , MP2 start with MP1 in the same time

Comment: That is the problem with `AsyncTask` when it is fired you can not cancel it. Maybe the best solution for you is to use `services` inside `AsyncTask` to stream radio.

Comment: You are welcome. I assume problem will occur if you stream radio and rotate the phone also.

Comment: i don't have a problem with orientation , because i use `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in all activities

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using startActivityForResult()?

Comment: please can you explain me morehow i can implement `startActivityForResult()`  to my code

Comment: Instead of calling context.startActivity(intent) try call context.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE). And in your first activity override onActivityResult() and resume the media player. If you have problems in the implementation try read about activity result in the docs. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html